# IFileExtensionRegistryService.GetExtensionsForContentType returns empty array for "CSharp" content type

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, envdte

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension that includes a nested/recursive search and replace. I want my search controls to match the Visual Studio "Find in Files" dialog (with some extra options). I'm trying to implement the "Look at these files types:" combo. I'm iterating over the available content types and using those to iterate over the extensions for that content as follows:

```
IContentTypeRegistryService content = ...
IFileExtensionRegistryService extensions = ...

foreach (IContentType type in content.ContentTypes)
{
    foreach (string extension in extensions.GetExtensionsForContentType(type))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, for some content types like "CSharp" (C++ and many other languages), the extension array returned from `GetExtensionsForContentType` is empty. I've looked and looked, but I can't find anything on MSDN, StackOverflow, or even the web that explains why or any alternative.

BTW: A strange thing is that the extensions that **do** return from the call are ones that normally **don't** show up in the "Find in Files" dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Well, wouldn't you know as soon as I'm so at my wits end I post the question here, it starts working. Don't know what was causing the behavior described here, but I'm now getting extensions for everything. I didn't do anything, it just started working, so this is very strange.

BTW: Still not getting what shows up in Find in Files. It looks like VS is concatenating extensions lists for the Find in Files. Not sure what criteria they use to decide what to concatenate, so I'll just have a lot bigger list of more explicit types.

Update:

Found out that it looks like the problem with the missing extensions happens when my Tool window was open that last time VS was shut down. VS remembers this and automatically shows it when run next. Unfortunately, it looks like the Package.Initialize and the `ToolWindowPane` are created **before** the content types are fully initialized. I've tried different values for `ProvideAutoLoadAttribute` (originally I had `SolutionExistsAndNotBuildingAndNotDebugging_string`, which seemed reasonable, but even `ShellInitialized_string` doesn't help.

Final Solution:

It looks like it is possible to detect the different situations. There are two `CreateToolWindow` overrides on the Package. One takes a `Guid` and the other a `Type`. The `Guid` version is called when the tool window is created **before** the content extensions are initialized. The `Type` version is called from the command you created to invoke the window so this definitely happens **after** the extensions are initialized. (You can also key on the fact that when the `Guid` version is called, your command is never actually executed. VS creates the window directly.)

It's not really ideal since the detection is really just based on circumstantial evidence. I would rather be able to query the `IFileExtensionRegistryService` directly to see if it is fully initialized, but no such property or method seems to exist. If I happen to run across a better solution, I'll update this question.